# Having problems iterating the data from a nested json Api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, api

I am fetching data

I have a brand property and I am trying to display it,  and I am trying to implement a click `setCurrentSelectedBrand` logic to diplay the data of that specific brand[object]. Currently I am getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'brand' of undefined` error in the Main Component, I dont know why

Data

```
[{
   "a_class":[
   {    
    "brand":"A-class",
    "id":"1",
    "year":"2015"
    "price":"12665"
    ...
    "engine_spec":{
     ...
     }
     ...
      }],

   "b_class":[
   {    
    "brand":"B-class",
    "id":"2",
    "year":"2016"
    "price":"12665"
    ...
    "engine_spec":{
     ...
     }
     ...
      }],
}
]
```

Main Component

```
const Cars = () => {

  const { cars, handleSelectBrand} = useContext(CarsContext)
    return (
        <div>
          {Object.keys(cars).map((key:any, index)=>{
            let brands:any = cars[key];
            return (     
              <div key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectBrand(key)} className='brand__list' >
              {brands[0].brand}
              </div>                  
              );})}
        <CarsDetails />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cars
```

Context

```
declare module 'axios' {
  export interface AxiosResponse<T = any> extends Promise<T> {}
}

export const CarsProvider:React.FC <IProps> = ({ children }  ) => {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [cars, setCars] =useState< any | ICars[] >([])
const [brands, setBrands] = useState([])
const [currentSelectedBrand, setCurrentSelectedBrand] = useState('')   

const handleSelectBrand = React.useCallback((brand) => {
  return setCurrentSelectedBrand(cars[brand]);
},[cars])

useEffect(()=>{
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await api.get('/cars', {
    });  
    setIsLoading(false)
    setCars([...response.data]);
    setCurrentSelectedBrand(response[Object.keys(response)[0]]);
    console.log(response.data)
  };
   

    fetchData()
},[brands, cars])
```

Comment: Note that `cars` is an array. Hence, when you iterate its members, you get the parent of the object you're expecting to get